# Executing code across all running gunicorn workers

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a simple flask pp in python using gunicorn which I am running like:
`gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 999 --log-level debug ers_intent_api:app`
. Is it possible to trigger a function to be run across all gunicorn workers?

for example say I have a simple app like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
# initialize using some default file on import 
ir = IrObject.fromFile(file_)

@app.route('/retrain', methods=["POST"])
def retrain():
    """updates global ir object from passed file"""
    global ir
    # update global object programtically - this will only execute for a single worker
    file_ = request.files.get("file")
    ir = IrObject.fromFile(file_)
```

Basically, I want to update the global ir object for each gunicorn worker, but as it is now only one worker would be affected.

Is there a way that I could trigger the above function for all gunicorn workers?

Thanks in advance

Update: reposting this as someone closed my previous question assuming this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423069/store-large-data-or-a-service-connection-per-flask-session) but this is not the case. The aforementioned question discusses persisting some object across requests to whereas I want to execute code across a set of gunicorn workers - very different things (unless I am misunderstanding the question).

Comment: you can save it database or file and every worker will have to read this on every request.