# flask pass variable from one function to another function

Tags: python, function, flash-message

As you can see the code.
I want to pass variable `q` from function `home()` into function `search()`.

```
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    result = Mylist.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html',result=result)
    q = request.form.get("q")

@app.route("/search.html")
def search():
        d = q
        var='%'+d+'%'
        result = Mylist.query.filter(Mylist.type.like(var)
        return render_template('search.html',result=result)
```

Comment: result = Mylist.query.filter(Mylist.type.like(var))

Comment: Your `q` in home is after the return stmt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611281 this might help you, I found it better than existing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where an `index.html` will contain:

```
<form action="/search.html" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="subscribe-form">
     <div class="form-group d-flex">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your search" name="q" id="q" value="{{q}}">
         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit px-3">
     </div>
 </form>
```

Now you will see `/search.html?q=top` in url now you can easily pass this `q=top` by using `q=request.args.get("q")`...

```
@app.route("/search.html",methods=['GET'])
def search():
        q =request.args.get("q")
        d=str(q)
        var='%'+d+'%'
        myresult = Mylist.query.filter(Mylist.type.like(var)| Mylist.title.like(var)).all()
```

Comment: I am saving a filename in function and I need to pass that variable/filename to another function. Your solution is not possible in such casses.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

A variable created and updated inside a function exists only for that function.

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)...

> *"If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body,
>   it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global."*

Solution: 
Create `q` as a variable **outside of functions**, this way it's not just trapped inside function `home` but instead is now universally available to any and all functions. Any function can use or update such a variable.

**Option 2:**

Alternatively, you could just try passing `q` as a **function parameter**.

In example below, you will call function `search` but with parameter `q` added. The `search` function itself will reference that same `q` as a thing called `input` (or choose your own name/word).

```
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    result = Mylist.query.all()
    q = request.form.get("q")
    search( q )
    return render_template('index.html',result=result)


@app.route("/search.html")
def search( input ):
    d = input
    var='%'+d+'%'
    result = Mylist.query.filter(Mylist.type.like(var)
    return render_template('search.html',result=result)
```

Comment: It is showing an error, TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input'

Comment: About _"search() missing 1 required parameter"_ sounds like you tried to call `search()` without giving it something to search for. As you can see, the function `def search( input ):` expects at least 1 thing to be provided as `input`...

Answer (score 1):

Define a global list append the variable from first view function to the list and access the last index value in the second view function.

```
var_list = []
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    result = Mylist.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html',result=result)
    q = request.form.get("q")
    var_list.append(q)

@app.route("/search.html")
def search():
        d = var_list.pop()
        var='%'+d+'%'
        result = Mylist.query.filter(Mylist.type.like(var)
        return render_template('search.html',result=result)
```

Answer (score -1):

your index.html will contain

```
<form action="/search.html" method="get" autocomplete="off" class="subscribe-form">
     <div class="form-group d-flex">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your search" name="q" id="q" value="{{q}}">
         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit px-3">
     </div>
 </form>
```

==================================================================================

Now you will see /search.html?q=top in url
now you can easily pass this q=top by 
using

```
q=request.args.get("q")
```