# How can I pass a variable to a python flask app?

Tags: python, variables, flask, routes

How can I pass `myvariable` to the `app` in the below code? `myvariable` is a variable that comes from the rest of the code rather than being received from the URL.

`@app.route("/myrout", methods=["GET"])`

`def myfunction(myvariable):`

Comment: you get "myvariable" from? global or from request?

Comment: If the myvariable is something in the global scope or apart of the module you do not need to pass it to the function you can just access like any other variable in a module.

Comment: I just answered my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a variable between Flask pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611216/how-to-pass-a-variable-between-flask-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
global myvariable=8

@app.route("/myrout", methods=["GET"])
def myfunction():
    global myvariable
    local_variable=myvariable
```

Comment: You should read this: [Are global variables thread-safe in Flask? How do I share data between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32815451/2745495)